# Cannot access any folders on my Desktop or Documents using cd

Tags: cd

I have recently been trying to access a folder that was created previously on my 64-bit computer using Ubuntu gotten through WSL. when I use mnt/c it says the file exists, but when I try to go to its actual directory it claims no file or directory exists. I've tried everything under the sun that could be found online as a means of solving it and seem to reach impediment after impediment. Trying to install and use Xming, I get a black screen. Downloading PuTTY through Ubuntu, I get an `unable to init server: could not connect connection refused` error. I can access my root depository, but that's all I can access. my home depository is completely empty, aside from a couple of hidden files. None of my folders or documents seem to be there, but because I used `cd` a week ago or documents can be accessed. I'm wondering why it chose to randomly stop now.

Comment: You've got some troubleshooting steps to complete, here, and you will need to edit your question to copy and paste their results:
* what commands have you run, as what user, from what working directory?
* what are the filesystem permissions of the files and directories with which you are interacting?
* what user is the owner of the files and directories?
* Why are you trying to use PuTTY?